# ¿System.err es un hilo que afecta a la ejecución de otros hilos?

Tags: java, hilos, volatile

Estoy intentando aprender un poco más de hilos y mirando el tipo `volatile` he encontrado una cosa rara que pasa con la clase `Thread`.

Tomado este [código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932269/3850595):

```
public class TestVolatile extends Thread{
    boolean keepRunning = true;

    public void run() {
        long count=0;
        while (keepRunning) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("Thread terminated."+count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestVolatile t = new TestVolatile();
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.keepRunning = false;
        System.out.println("keepRunning set to false.");
    }
}
```

Vemos que efectivamente, se ejecuta indefinidamente, ya que (hasta donde lo entiendo) la variable no es visible dentro del hilo.

Si cambiamos la declaración de `boolean keepRunning = true;` por `volatile boolean keepRunning = true;`, el hilo termina, ya que entra, duerme y posteriormente cambia la variable al estar visible. Todo correcto.

Pasa que si cambias el while donde aumentas el contador `count` por, por ejemplo:

```
while (keepRunning) {
    count++;
    System.err.print(".");
}
```

Pasamos a tener un proceso que **siempre termina**, sea la variable `volatile` o no y la verdad que me ha dejado perplejo.

---

Con las dudas, he cogido otro [ejemplo de aquí](http://jarroba.com/multitarea-e-hilos-en-java-con-ejemplos-ii-runnable-executors/) y he modificado una parte parecida del código así:

```
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    System.err.print(".");
}
```

Y ahora veo que si le pongo `System.err.print(".");` dentro del while de `MainExecutor` los hilos funcionan y terminan, pero la consola se vuelve loca, limpiándose a cada escritura de uno de los hilos.

¿Qué es lo que causa este comportamiento? El llamar a `System.err` está creando otro hilo que interfiere con los otros y por eso volatile termina y la salida de los otros se ve alterada?

Comment: invocar a `System.err.print` no crea ningún hilo, pero _probablemente_ provoca que la cache del CPU acabe bajando `keepRunning` a la memoria fisica, por ello la version que no usa volatile resulta funcionando similar a la que si. Ten en cuenta que volatile causa que la JVM no permita que la variable se almacene en la cache del procesador sino directamente en la memoria fisica.

Answer (score 2):

Java se limita a garantizar que las lecturas/escrituras a variables "compartidas" (distintos threads) será consistente si usas `volatile`.

Si no usas `volatile` , el comportamiento es no predecible.

En tu primer ejemplo, sin `volatile`, parece que el loop está "demasiado ocupado" como para tomarse el tiempo de checkear si la variable fue modificada en otro thread (de hecho, en otro espacio de memoria), y como no tiene la obligación de hacerlo... pues no lo hace, y nunca se entera del cambio.

Que sí se entere cuando agregas un `System.err.print` ... no interesa mucho explicarlo, como normalmente no interesa mucho explicar el comportamiento ante situaciones -por diseño- no predecibles. Basta con adivinar que el llamado a ese método hace que la JVM "levante un poco la mirada" y se obligue a sí misma a sincronizar datos de los threads vivos. Pero no tiene nada que ver específicamente con `System.err`
En mi caso, observo el mismo comportamiento si solo hago una llamada a , por ejemplo, `Thread.currentThread().isAlive()`

```
   while (keepRunning) {
            if(!Thread.currentThread().isAlive()) count++; 
            count++;
  }
```